# how to edit xml root attributes with python

Tags: python, xml

Recently ive been messing around with editing xml files with a python script for a project im working on but i cant figure out how to edit the attributes of the root element.

for example the xml file would say:

```
<root width="200">
  <element1>
  </element1>
</root>
```

what i want to do is have my code find the width attribute and change it to some other value, i know how to edit elements after the root but not the root itself

[code im using for changing attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hwsjg.png)

Comment: You might want to show your current code.

Comment: i havent done any code for it i just dont know what to do and cant find anything about it so i thought id ask

Comment: Then show the code that you know can change any attributes but at the root level. Should not be too hard to write when you already know it.

Comment: For the future: If you have text, don't post screenshots of text - post the text. That's easier for everyone. So is telling you what specifically is wrong with a certain code sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following module `xml.etree.ElementTree`. With this module you can set up attributes using `xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.set()`
Here is an example of snippet you could use:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('input.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
root.set('width','400')
print(root.attrib)

tree.write('output.xml')
```

Comment: im dumb, literally did that but forgot the quotes, thanks